# Options for company-proprietary Windows app installation?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I need to create an installer for an internal company app that will be used by some field employees.  Below are the options as I understand them, but hoping I am missing something that would be much less complicated than these choices!

Sideloading: too difficult for these guys to install/update!

Windows Store for Business: appears to require that we have Azure organizational accounts.  The app does use Azure and the users do have Azure Active Directory accounts but they aren't tied to our corporate IT accounts  (*.*onmicrosoft.com).  I'm in a services group of a large organization, not sure if we could be our own "organization" separate from corporate (our Azure account is separate), still researching this.

Public Windows Store: maybe ok, but seems like an unnecessary risk.  To download workpacks the user must have Azure AD credentials.  I should probably add some additional security if I go this route..suggestions?

Is there another way?

Comment: One method I've currently suggested is that you create it on the public store but make it private, ie; app can only be installed with a link and cannot be found directly on the store listing. Additional to this you make the app only accessible to users with a redemption code which you can distribute to individuals whom you'd like to access the app. I know this is not perfect, but for now I think this is a good option to consider.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith, Thanks for the comment, but not sure I follow "app can only be installed with a link and cannot be found directly on the store listing".  Wouldn't that mean the downloader would end up sideloading the app?  If there's a way to install with "one-click" like an msi that would be fine, but these users aren't going to be able to download, locate downloaded zip, unzip, right-click 'run-as-powershell-script'.   If there IS a one-click solution please let me know as my hours of googling have not uncovered this.

Comment: @DennaD, Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution) out! Under this you can check out "Hiding the app in the Store and using promotional codes"! The installation for the end user is done via the store itself and is not sideloading!

Comment: That looks perfect.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Bummer...doesn't seem that the public windows store will accept an Azure AD tenant login.  The users would have to create separate windows store accounts.  Thanks for trying though!!!